# Numpy digitize included bin edge by absolute value

Tags: python, numpy

For the `np.digitize` function, I have a distribution of data about zero (includes negative and positive values). I would like the bin edge to be `right=False` for the positive values, but `right=True` for negative ones (i.e. were I to take the absolute value, the lower bound is inclusive in the bin).

```
>>> x = np.array([-10, -4, -1.2, -0.3, 3, 4, 7])
>>> bins = np.array([-8, -4, 0, 4, 8])
>>> np.digitize(x,bins,right=????)
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

Is there an alternative method to handle this other than a conditional set:

```
if x <= -8:
    return 0
elif -8 < x <= -4:
    return 1
elif -4 < x <= 0:
    return 2
elif 0 < x < 4:
    return 3
elif 4 <= x < 8:
    return 4
elif 8 <= x:
    return 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift some of the boundaries by the smallest possible amount using `numpy.nextafter`:

```
>>> bins = bins.astype(x.dtype)
>>> bins = np.nextafter(bins, bins + (bins <= 0))

# apply
>>> np.digitize(x, bins)
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
# zero also goes to the right bin
>>> np.digitize(0, bins)
array(2)
```

Upon inspection

```
>>> bins
array([-8.e+000, -4.e+000,  5.e-324,  4.e+000,  8.e+000])
# ndarray.__str__ rounds, but casting to list reveals
>>> bins.tolist()
[-7.999999999999999, -3.9999999999999996, 5e-324, 4.0, 8.0]
```

we see that zero was shifted to something looking suspiciously like a denormal which may or may not cause problems on some platforms.

Just to be sure to be sure we can avoid this issue going the other way:

```
>>> bins = np.array([-8, -4, 0, 4, 8])
>>> bins = bins.astype(x.dtype)
>>> bins = np.nextafter(bins, np.minimum(bins, 0))
>>> np.digitize(x, bins, True)
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
>>> np.digitize(0, bins, True)
array(2)
>>> bins.tolist()
[-8.0, -4.0, 0.0, 3.9999999999999996, 7.999999999999999]
```